# SAS Clustering Creating a Variable whose values indicate what cluster obs belong to

Tags: sas, cluster-analysis

I am new to clustering. In the project I've been working on I ran a PCA of several test variables. I came up with 5 factors/components with eigenvalues greater than 1. I standardized the variables that loaded onto these components and I am now clustering. Based on the results that Proc Cluster gave me (ccc, pseudo ect.) I determined that I want 5 clusters as well. Now I am trying to pick out "defining" characteristics of each of those 5 clusters and examine their make up (what race, gender, age) group makes up these clusters. To do this I am trying to incorporate a new variable into my datset which assigns each participant (by ID) a number between 1-5 indicating what cluster that participant belongs to. However, all the gides I find on the internet only tell me how to determine the optimal # of clusters. I already know how many clusters I want, I just need to create this variable that tells me what participant goes into what cluster. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you know how to use the SAS datastep?  Also, are you planning to do a clustering algorithm, or are you just assigning the cluster based on [whatever] and leaving it fixed?  Can you include some examples of the data and how you intend to define what cluster someone belongs to (say a small dataset with 3-4 variables and 10-15 rows, assign 2-3 clusters to)?

Comment: You may wish to look at the `treeout=` option in `proc cluster` alongside the `ncl=` option in `proc tree`.